# Cannot connect to sharepoint online via powershell?

Tags: powershell, parameters, sharepoint-online

I am trying to connect to sharepoint via the powershell using the following, which has worked in the past, i am global admin, sharepoint admin etc etc,

```
#Set Parameters
$AdminSiteURL="https://***MYSITE***-Admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL="https://***MYSITE***.sharepoint.com/sites/corporate"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online Admin Center
Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
 
#Enable SharePoint Designer for the site collection
Set-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False
```

The error i get is,

```
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
Connect-SPOService : Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) did not get a response from the Login server.
At line:6 char:1
+ Connect-SPOService -Url $AdminSiteURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Connect-SPOService], IdcrlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.IdcrlException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.Connec
   tSPOService

Set-SPOSite : No connection available. Use Connect-SPOService before running this CmdLet.
At line:9 char:1
+ Set-SPOSite -Identity $SiteURL -DenyAddAndCustomizePages $False
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Set-SPOSite], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell.SetSite
```

Any help?

I tried deleting the sharepoint online management shell and reinstall with no success.

I also turned off MFA for this account (i waited a day aswell)

Answer (score -2):

1.Check the permission to the the site. You can refer to [the article](https://sharepointmaven.com/2-ways-see-users-access-sharepoint/) .

2.Check if the tenant have enabled MFA. You can refer to the document [Set up multifactor authentication for Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/security-and-compliance/set-up-multi-factor-authentication?view=o365-worldwide#turn-off-legacy-per-user-mfa)